# Acessar atributo de uma classe em um Controller ASP NET

Tags: asp.net

Eu gostaria em meu sistema Crud ASP.NET fazer com que uma imagem na forma de cadeado ficasse desabilitado quando um determinado perfil de usuário logar no sistema, o nome desse controller abaixo se chama ManterFinalidadeController
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha ideia é a seguinte, aproveitar e guardar em Session as informarções que estão na Controller LogginController.cs e chamar na ManterFinalidadeController, porém eu montei a primeira parte do acesso ao atributo da classe que vem vazio e queria saber como traze-la, segue abaixo o código do ManterFinalidadeController:

public JsonResult _ListarFinalidades()
        {
            List finalidades = new List();

```
        using (var ws = new VREWebServiceClient())
        {
            ObterFinalidadeResponse obj = new ObterFinalidadeResponse();
            /* Eu */ 
            BSeguranca BSeguranca = new BSeguranca();

            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            int Recebe_NMUsuario = usuario.NUsuario;


            obj = ws.ObterFinalidade(false);
            bool historico;
            string acaoHistorico = string.Empty;

            var objHistorico = obj.Finalidade.Where(w => w.DatVigncAte != null);

            foreach (var item in obj.Finalidade)
            {
                historico = false;

                string acaoVisualizarFinalidade = String.Format("<a href=\"/ManterFinalidade/VisualizarFinalidade?codigo={0}\" title=\"Dados da Finalidade\"><img src=\"/Content/images/detalhes.png\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" width=\"16px\" border=\"0\"></a>", item.CodFinld);
                string acaoAssociarDeclaracaoFinalidade = String.Format("<a href=\"/ManterFinalidade/AssociarDeclaracaoFinalidade?codigo={0}\" title=\"Associar Declaração - Finalidade\"><img src=\"/Content/images/associar.png\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" width=\"16px\" border=\"0\"></a>", item.NumFinld);

                foreach (var x in objHistorico)
                {
                    if (x.CodFinld == item.CodFinld)
                        historico = true;
                }

                if (historico)
                    acaoHistorico = "<img src=\"/Content/images/historico.png\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" title=\"Visualizar Histórico\" width=\"16px\" border=\"0\" class=\"accordion\">";
                else
                    acaoHistorico = "<img src=\"/Content/images/historico_off.png\" title=\"Visualizar Histórico\" width=\"16px\" border=\"0\">";

                if (item.DatVigncAte == null)
                {
                    finalidades.Add(new EFinalidadeGrid()
                    {
                        CodFinld = item.CodFinld,
                        DesFinld = item.DesFinld,
                        DatVigncDe = item.DatVigncDe,
                        DatVigncAte = item.DatVigncAte,
                        HtmlAcoes = String.Format("{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{1}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{2}", acaoHistorico, acaoVisualizarFinalidade, acaoAssociarDeclaracaoFinalidade)
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            Retorno = finalidades
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Na proxima imagem, quero capturar o valor do atributo NUsuario que é igual a 16783 para perfil técnico e comparar com a linha 60 se for perfil técnico, mostra a imagem desabilitada, senão habilita caso for outro perfil:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar, o que esta faltando para trazer os dados preenchidos na imagem 2?

Obrigado pessoal

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal,

```
O esquema era esse mesmo:
```

Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
usuario.atributo = valor;
   Mas no momento não será isso que vou usar, haverá uma funcionalidade que usarei pra comparar com Enum.

Obrigado pessoal.